# Need help to upload files on multiple sftp servers quickly using PHP

Tags: php, sftp

I have bunch of files which I need to upload to different sftp servers. How i can achieve this quickly using PHP? any help on this appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why do you want to use PHP for this, instead of rsync or anything else that is better suited?

Comment: Hey there, hope you're doing well. We are not here to solve the job for you, but assist, so please consider paying more attention to your question quality.

question guidelines - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

You definitely are aiming too broad, try to be more specific and include more details. e.g. What you tried, what went wrong, describe your situation better

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need the `ssh2` extension for PHP.

Then, make a connection to SSH with it and then open SFTP.
Here is the example from [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php):

```php
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$stream = fopen('ssh2.sftp://' . intval($sftp) . '/path/to/file', 'r');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Roboroads. Really appreciate your quick help. Is it a feasible solution to upload bunch of files to n number of sftp servers which will loop on array of files and array of sftp servers? I mean is it faster enough and safer?

Comment: Faster: no. Secure: Well, as secure as sftp is. PHP is not really the tool for this job but it's possible. If you just want to upload files to servers, just use FileZilla.